# Fetching millions of records from database using ormlite

Tags: android, ormlite

Hello I am working on application where I have database having millions of records, I want to display rows in recycler view in efficient way, Fetching millions of record and storing them in arraylist will not be a good solution, I wanted to know how can I efficiently fetch these many records using ormlite and does not blow up memory while using application. App should stay response as well, Any thoughts/solution on this?

Comment: "I want to display all rows in recycler view" -- no user is interested in scrolling through millions of `RecyclerView` items.

Comment: also what @CommonsWare said is definitely true, if you dont want to provide any "filtering out" mechanism your `RecyclerView` will be absolutely useless

Comment: @CommonsWare I wont display all, I will add pagination. can you guide me with code snippet ?

Comment: @pskink yes I corrected my question "I want to display all rows in recycler view using pagination"

Comment: pagination has nothing to do with it, if you dont want to filter out the items, nobody will scroll a milion item list

Comment: visit this https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b#.lreq8y7ic

Comment: Not sure why ORMLite is needed. It's just a SQLite question. That being said, this is worth a read. http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

Comment: @pskink My goal here is to show records I can take care of filtering and all, All I want to know is how can I load entries using cursor may be some other mechanism which would keep my recyclerview responsive, But I want to do it using ormlite

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using ormlite I cannot switch to plain sql right now, I know old way is to get Dao and query data which would return arraylist but keeping all those records in arraylist wont do any good for my application,

Comment: `"All I want to know is how can I load entries using cursor"` so use `com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults#getRawCursor()`

Comment: Did you read the post? It gives you queries to not return all the elements and using a Cursor doesn't return an Arraylist